# Is it mandatory to submit app for app center in facebook review?

Tags: facebook

i am submitting an app for facebook login review.There is also option to submit for app center details to review .So is it necessary to submit app to app center also ?

Thank you
Veebha

Comment: Only if you want to be listed in App Center … If you just want to get some permissions approved, then you don’t need to submit for App Center.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i don't want my app in app center .So it means its not mandatory to submit app to app centre.